# Investment problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Fernando invested money in a 3 year CD that returned the equivalent of 4.4% simple interest. He invested \$2000 less in an 18 month CD that had 3% return. If the total amount of interest from these investments was \$706.50, determine how much was invested in each CD.

Not sure how to do this.

Does 4.4% simple interest mean each year or at the end of 3 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the interest rates are annual rates.  Here are some hints.

Let the amount invested in the three-year CD be $x$.  Then the interest earned over three years is $(3)(0.044)x$ ($3$ years, times $4.4\% = 0.044$ per year, times the amount invested).

- If the $18$-month CD had $\$2,000$ less invested, how would you express this in terms of $x$?
- What would be the interest earned on this CD (following the same idea as for the first CD)?
- What is the equation that links the two amounts of interest?  (Hint: They add up to $\$706.50$.)

This will allow you to solve for $x$ (the first amount), and then the second amount which is related to $x$.

More explicit hints:

> This is the equation to solve for $x$:  $(3)(0.044)x + (1.5)(0.03)(x-2000) = 706.50$.  Then $x$ and $x-2000$ are the two CD amounts.